# MySqli UPDATE, detect if entry doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am updating the DB when I receive some data from an API I'm using.

And I changed `value` to something that is not in my DB, while I'm testing to see if it will give off an error. It did not, everything went on as if the var was a match and the DB was updated.

What would be a way to check for this?

```
foreach($message_id_array as $key=>$value) {

$query = "UPDATE `sms_messages_tbl` 
SET `delivery2_api_to_enduser`= '1',
`delivery2_response_time` = UTC_TIMESTAMP(),
`delivery2_response_api_ip`= '".$ip."',
`delivery2_response_from_api`= '".$message_status_array[$key]."'
WHERE `transaction_sms_id` = '".$value."' ";


if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {                                                    
     echo ''.$message_status_array[$key].':'.$value.':OK';                                                      
} else {
     echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}                                       
$conn->close();                                                         
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the affected rows after executing the query.. see this link - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error returned because MySQL ***does not*** return any errors on `UPDATE` ( except the syntax schema-related ones of course ).

You can go into `phpMyAdmin` because I guess you're using it, and run the same update with some dummy values, you'll see the result is a `success` with `0 affected rows`.

The update still happened successfully and it affected no rows because none met the requirements.

Just so you can get a clearer idea of what happened, you can look for the number of affected rows using the following:

```
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo ''.$message_status_array[$key].':'.$value.':OK';
    echo $conn->affected_rows . ' affected';
}
```

It will say the update was fine and the number of affected rows is `0`.

Comment: @Borsn , yes, you can do `if ( $conn->query($query) && $conn->affected_rows )`. This way you're sure it executed fine and it affected at least one entry.

Comment: `( $conn->query($query) && $conn->affected_rows )` I'm not sure what it does, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You don't always need to check for `== true`. If the variable that you are checking returns true by itself, there's no need to write it down anymore. Therefore `if ( $conn->query($query) === true && $conn->affected_rows )` equals to `if ( $conn->query($query) && $conn->affected_rows )`.

The firs one, returns true in case of success. Therefore no need for `=== true`. Second one, returns the number of affected rows, in case it is successfull. PHP interprets every number aside 0, as true, therefore you don't need to check `$conn->affected_rows > 0`.  Please mark as accepted if it helped.

Comment: Thanks! And will do! :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a select request to the database "Select * FROM table WHERE 'id' = $value".

And then run mysqli_num_rows on that. If the result != 0, do your SET Query.

Comment: But then I would have to run 2 queries. Is that recommended? Thats what I first intended to do. However I'm worried It will longer...my db will be expanding a lot. And id rather no query is too many times.

Comment: Then you should probably usw affected rows, I don't really like it, select seamse to be more reliable to me.     http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php    http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp

Comment: Sorry, but affected rows doesn't work on SET, as far as I know

Comment: This is what I'm using now: `if ($conn->affected_rows == 0) {}else if ($conn->affected_rows == 1) {}` works great for me.